# Symfony check-box event, ajax with several fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I use symfony and on twig have render some array data and have check-box, in js, for event click, for check box, create ajax and send data in another action. My question  how to send more parameters, now send not only id, because add id to tag input attribute, but need add address too some where. Where add `address?`:

```
{% for taskExecution in taskExecutions %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="searchType" type="checkbox" name="SharingNotification" id={{ taskExecution.id }}>
                    <label class="searchtype2label"></label>
                </input>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ taskExecution.address }}
            </td>
{% endfor %}
```

my js

```
$('.searchType').click(function(event) {
    var objToSend = {};
    objToSend[event.target.id] = $(this).is(":checked") === true ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/app_dev.php/api/bound_invoice/rows/froms/tasks',
        data: {ids: objToSend},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('it worked');
            alert(data);
            $('#container').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('it completed');
        }
    });
}
```

);

I want send another attribute, example `taskExecution.address`
like this

```
        objToSend['address'] = [event.target.address];
```

how can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like the following should do the trick:

```
$('.searchType').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/app_dev.php/api/bound_invoice/rows/froms/tasks',
        data: {
            ids: { event.target.id : $(this).is(":checked") === true ? 1 : 0 },
            address : event.target.address
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('it worked');
            alert(data);
            $('#container').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('it completed');
        }
    });
}
```

);

The problem with your code was that you were adding everything you wanted to submit to the "ids" property of your data object. With my change, `ids` will be passed as 1 or 0, and `address` will be passed with the desired value.

Comment: in console `event.target.address
undefined`

Comment: I need add some where parameter `address` and then call in js, how add parameter ?

Comment: `event.target.address` is *your* code. I've demonstrated how to add the parameter to the AJAX request, if the property you put in your question doesn't exist then you need to use a different value.